# Entity Database Add/Update method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What would be the most elegant way to refactor the following method?

```
 public void AddOrUpdateDesignCVT(DesignInformation designInformation,
                            CommonTransformerProperties commonTransformerProperties,
                            SecondaryWindings secondaryWindings,
                            CapacitorVoltageDivider capacitorVoltageDivider,
                            IntermediateVoltageTransformer intermediateVoltageTransformer,
                            SpecialDesignInformation specialDesignInformation,
                            TransformerLimits transformerLimits)
    {

        GenerateWindingInstructions(designInformation);

        Design design;
        using (var context = new DesignContext())
        {

            if (!DesignExist(designInformation.DesignID))
            {



                context.DesignInformation.Add(designInformation);
                context.CommonTransformerPropeteries.Add(commonTransformerProperties);
                context.SecondaryWindings.Add(secondaryWindings);
                context.CapacitorVoltageDivider.Add(capacitorVoltageDivider);
                context.IntermediateVoltageTransformer.Add(intermediateVoltageTransformer);
                context.SpecialDesignInformation.Add(specialDesignInformation);
                context.TransformerLimits.Add(transformerLimits);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return;
            }
        }

            using (var newcontext = new DesignContext())
            {
                design = GetDesingByNameFromDatabase(newcontext, designInformation.DesignID, designInformation.Technology);

                UpdateSecondaryWindings(design, newcontext, designInformation, secondaryWindings);

                UpdateSpecialWires(design, newcontext, designInformation, specialDesignInformation);

                newcontext.SaveChanges();
            }
            int dbId = design.DesignInformation.DataBaseID;

            design.DesignInformation = designInformation;
            design.DesignInformation.DataBaseID = dbId;

            design.CommonTransformerProperties = commonTransformerProperties;
            design.CommonTransformerProperties.DataBaseID = dbId;

            design.SecondaryWindings = secondaryWindings;
            design.SecondaryWindings.DataBaseID = dbId;

            design.CapacitorVoltageDivider = capacitorVoltageDivider;
            design.CapacitorVoltageDivider.DataBaseID = dbId;

            design.IntermediateVoltageTransformer = intermediateVoltageTransformer;
            design.IntermediateVoltageTransformer.DataBaseID = dbId;

            design.SpecialDesignInformation = specialDesignInformation;
            design.SpecialDesignInformation.DataBaseID = dbId;

            using (var newcontext = new DesignContext())
            {
                newcontext.Entry(design.CommonTransformerProperties).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                newcontext.Entry(design.SecondaryWindings).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                newcontext.Entry(design.CapacitorVoltageDivider).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                newcontext.Entry(design.IntermediateVoltageTransformer).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                newcontext.Entry(design.SpecialDesignInformation).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                newcontext.Entry(design.DesignInformation).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                newcontext.SaveChanges();
                return;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) Possibly better structure**

Since information from `DesignInformation`, `CommonTransformerProperties`, ..., `TransformerLimits` objects seem to be semantically linked, it should be grouped into a single object type (maybe a `Transformer`). The EF model should be similar to the class below (greatly simplified).

```
class Transformer
{
   int TransformerId { get; set; }

   DesignInformation designInformation;
   CommonTransformerProperties commonTransformerProperties,
   SecondaryWindings secondaryWindings,
   CapacitorVoltageDivider capacitorVoltageDivider,
   IntermediateVoltageTransformer intermediateVoltageTransformer,
   SpecialDesignInformation specialDesignInformation,
   TransformerLimits transformerLimits
}
```

The real gain here is that you can have a single ID to be generated, but you have to change child types to link them to the parent. I.e. `DesignInformation`, `CommonTransformerProperties`, ..., `TransformerLimits` should also have a `TransformerId` specified. Persistence code should be simpler:

```
    using (var newcontext = new DesignContext())
    {
        design = GetDesingByNameFromDatabase(newcontext, designInformation.DesignID, designInformation.Technology);

        UpdateSecondaryWindings(design, newcontext, designInformation, secondaryWindings);

        UpdateSpecialWires(design, newcontext, designInformation, specialDesignInformation);

        newcontext.SaveChanges();
    }

    int dbId = design.DesignInformation.DataBaseID;

    design.DesignInformation = designInformation;
    design.DesignInformation.DataBaseID = dbId;

    design.CommonTransformerProperties = commonTransformerProperties;
    design.CommonTransformerProperties.DataBaseID = dbId;

    design.SecondaryWindings = secondaryWindings;
    design.SecondaryWindings.DataBaseID = dbId;

    design.CapacitorVoltageDivider = capacitorVoltageDivider;
    design.CapacitorVoltageDivider.DataBaseID = dbId;

    design.IntermediateVoltageTransformer = intermediateVoltageTransformer;
    design.IntermediateVoltageTransformer.DataBaseID = dbId;

    design.SpecialDesignInformation = specialDesignInformation;
    design.SpecialDesignInformation.DataBaseID = dbId;
```

should be:

```
    using (var newcontext = new DesignContext())
    {
        var newTransformer = new Transformer();
        newcontext.Transformer.Add(newTransformer);

        design = GetDesingByNameFromDatabase(newcontext, designInformation.DesignID, designInformation.Technology);
        UpdateSecondaryWindings(design, newcontext, designInformation, secondaryWindings);
        UpdateSpecialWires(design, newcontext, designInformation, specialDesignInformation);

        newTransformer.DesignInformation = designInformation;
        newTransformer.CommonTransformerProperties = commonTransformerProperties;
        // ...

        newcontext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

EF will automatically push generated identifier to all children entities.

**2) Database context usage**

Database context should not be disposed so often. Usually Unit of work pattern is used to simplify its usage and also group everything that must be saved together (i.e. in a transaction). More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666824/entity-framework-and-context-dispose) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663754/entity-framework-4-lifespan-scope-of-context-in-a-winform-application).

This will spare you from passing the context for calls like:

```
        design = GetDesingByNameFromDatabase(newcontext, designInformation.DesignID, designInformation.Technology);
        UpdateSecondaryWindings(design, newcontext, designInformation, secondaryWindings);
        UpdateSpecialWires(design, newcontext, designInformation, specialDesignInformation);
```

Those functions can use the context by just calling `DesignContext.Instance` method where the method would look like this:

```
    public static Instance
    {
        get
        {
            // Dirty (non thread-safe) check
            if (UnitOfWorkStore.GetData(DATACONTEXT_KEY) == null)
            {
                lock (objSync)
                {
                    // Thread-safe check
                    if (UnitOfWorkStore.GetData(DATACONTEXT_KEY) == null)
                    {
                        var context = new DesignContext();
                        UnitOfWorkStore.SetData(DATACONTEXT_KEY, context);
                    }
                }
            }
            return (DesignContext)UnitOfWorkStore.GetData(DATACONTEXT_KEY);
        }
    }
```

An improvement is to using Dependency Injection and to have the context injected. The whole process is explained in great detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172448/how-to-inject-the-entity-framework-dbcontext-into-the-configurationbasedreposito). Of course, other DI frameworks - such as [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) - can be used.